# Generic CAN XCP API

Tags: api, interface, can-bus

I'm trying to design an application that involves communicating over a CAN bus with the XCP standard protocol.  The API should expose methods mapping directly to supported XCP commands, e.g. xcpProgramStart() > PROGRAM_START (0xD2).  Calling these methods should output the corresponding CAN messages for a preconfigured CAN ID, e.g.

```
0005  8  D2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

It doesn't seem like such a thing would be too difficult to implement, but I wanted to check if it's already been done.  Nothing ruins the satisfaction of good work like knowing it was needless.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check this early implementation?
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xcp

It's written in haskell and uses Ethernet on the physical layer. But the core module seems to be quite similar to what you requested.